# C# system.management is not loaded

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, wmi, system.management

I'm trying to use system.management in a C# windows forms app in VS 2017, but it just won't work. 
Here is a code sample:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Management;

namespace MyWMIapp
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void okButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@”\\MyComputerName\root\CIMV2″);

        }
    }
}
```

At: "using System.Management;" it tells me: this is not needed/used.

At: "ManagementScope scope = ......" it tells me: not found (maybe a missing using-Directive), and is red underlined.

Both is obviously wrong. I'm loading it and I'm using it. Why don't both lines "see" each other?

Comment: Do you have the System.Management assembly in your project?

Comment: Don't I do this by adding the line: using System.Management; or is there more to do?

Comment: Did you create this windows forms app in VS 2017? i.e is it the new project format (edit csproj file and does it say `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">`)?

Comment: @jemandanders see if it in the references for your project.  It is the first item under the project name in solution explorer.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I had to add it there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add reference to System.Management.dll to your project.